# How to set up or where to find my ideal free Windows 7 media player?

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, media-player

I want the following features in a media player, or a combination of media players (ie: one for music and other for videos):

- When open, start playing please
- Configurable global hotkeys (next, previous, play/pause at least)
- Configurable file deletion hotkey
- Folder monitoring (updates the libraries automatically based on one folder's contents)
- Plays video (mkv, avi, etc)
- Deinterlace as default
- Remember that I want it to shuffle the songs, and shuffle the first song.
- Play video at original resolution even if it doesn't fits the screen.
- Simple interface
- Audio crossfading
- Don't make me look for codecs.

Current solutions (with respective missing features):

- **The KMPlayer** -> on Windows 7 it is buggy. Couldn't make folder monitoring work yet. Doesn't shuffles the first song. However, it's my #1 choice on Windows XP.
- **SMPlayer** -> hotkeys aren't working on Windows 7, no folder monitoring
- VLC -> needs plugin for global hotkeys, deinterlacing isn't default and must be activated at each video. No folder monitoring. It forgets to shuffle each session. No crossfading.
- jetAudio -> doesn't start playing right away, and it's difficult to play videos, horrible interface.
- Windows Media Player -> global hotkeys only with plugin. As far as I know it is always missing a codec.
- Media Player Classic -> Couldn't find global hotkeys, no folder monitoring.

Maybe the solution is in one or a combination of the options above, all I need is to configure them properly.

Comment: To be noted, this is potentially a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/7407/music-player-alternative-to-windows-media-player althought detailed. I will leave it to the community to make a final decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently using

- For audio files

  1. [Foobar 2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/)
  2. [Foobar delete current song plugin](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=53305)

>

- For video files

  1. Windows Media Player
  2. [Comunity Combined Codec Pack (CCCP)](http://cccp-project.net/)
  3. [Wmpkeys](http://wmpkeys.sourceforge.net/)

The only thing I miss now is the ability to delete the currently playing video file with a global hotkey

Answer (score 2):

Try [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/download-media-player-classic-hc.html). For x264 you will need CoreAVC for best results. It may not cover your music needs, but it's my best choice for videos playback on Windows.

Comment: Couldn't find global hotkeys, must install with codecs, no folder monitoring.

Comment: MPC-HC has codecs already included. It shall work out of the box. It is really missing global hotkeys though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/about/features/)?

Answer (score 1):

MPC for video, [Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) for audio is a fine freeware combination.

if you don't mind spending a few quid, then i recommend [Neuview Media Player](http://www.neuviewed.com/neuview6/generate.php?pagename=home/index#REWARD) for video and [Spider Player](http://spider-player.com/) (there is also a free version available, limited converter and recorder capabilities) for audio, two stunning programs.

Answer (score 0):

KMPlayer is very comfortable for playing video, plays virtually *anything*. Never tried it with audio.

for Audio, I would recommend [spotify](http://spotify.com), if this kind of "approach" is good for you (i.e. you have constant connection to internet, don't own large collection of music and don't need equalizer).

Though it doesn't have configurable hotkeys (but if you own multimedia keyboard, media keys will control it).

hope this helps.

Comment: "The KMPlayer" is great, it has configurable hotkeys, and even global hotkeys. There is also a very famous KDE KMPlayer, but this question is about Windows media players.

Answer (score 0):

Get the install center from Zoomplayer trial and you shouldn't miss any codecs in Windows Media Player anymore.

It will use ffdshow for most decoding which has great options (that it will remember), including various deinterlacing algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

**Media Player Jukebox** will handle your audio challenges. **WMP** or **JetAudio** will handle the video.